# Particular Integral - Where am i going wrong!?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I really need someone to help me work out what I'm doing wrong or if I'm not and it's the question!

The equation is stated as:
$$y'' + 25y= 150\cos(5z)$$

I have found the auxiliary equation, which I know is right, as 
$$m^2 + 25 = 0$$ 
and thus the roots as $m = \pm 5i$. I know the complementary function is $$(A\cos(5z)+B\sin(5z))$$
and that's right. The bit I really don't know what I'm doing wrong is finding the particular integral (or particular solution if that's how you know it). I take a trial solution of
$$y_p = C\cos(5z)+D\sin(5z).$$
I then differentiate twice to find
$$y'_p = -5C\sin(5z)+5D\cos(5z)$$
and
$$y''_p = -25C\cos(5z)-25D\sin(5z)$$
Substitute them into the original equation $$-25C\cos(5z)-25D\sin(5z) + 25(C\cos(5z)+D\sin(5z)) = 150\cos(5z).$$
The problem here is I cannot find a solution for $C$ and $D$ individually as they cancel out. But the answer is $15\sin(5z)z$ and I have no idea how to get this answer. If anyone can help me see where I'm going wrong that would be wonderful as I cannot see what else to try. Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean $$y'' + 25 y$$ or something similar?

Comment: Sorry, yes I did mean 25y, I was confusing myself with the axuillary equation sorry!

Comment: When the trial solution has terms already in the complementary function, you have to do something else, right?  Look in your textbook.

Comment: Oh for heavens sake. Really should have seen that! I will endeavour to have another go.

Comment: @Emily: Try $$y_p = z( a \cos 5z + b \sin 5z)$$ The reason being, we already have $y_c$ that includes those same trig terms.See: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem truly is $$y'' + 25= 150\cos(5z),$$ then you can just integrate twice and the problem is done.

More likely, it is supposed to be $$y'' + 25y = 150\cos(5z).$$ In this case, your problem is that the homogeneous solution takes the form $$y_h(z) = A \cos(5z) + B\sin(5z)$$ and you're trial particular solution would be $$y_p(z) = C \cos(5z) + D \sin(5z)$$ but these terms are already part of the homogeneous solution so you need to instead try $$y_p(z) = C z\cos(5z) + D z\sin(5z)$$

Comment: Thank you! I really should have seen that but I've been working on similar problems all day and got myself in a rut and needed someone to point it out!